# How do I get binding in AngularJS to work with iframe content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I'm building an app that is basically a CMS / Website editor. When the app loads I have a set of tools that allow the user to change their sites textual content, colors, images and a few other features.

The data is being controlled using AngularJS Models and controllers. Currently all the templates the users can use from are html pages that I need to load into an iframe inside the app.

Currently I have a controller that will be responsible for the iframe and the html content inside of it.

Controller looks like this.

```
function SiteTempCtrl($scope, MainDM)
{
    $scope.dm = MainDM;
    $scope.percent = 100;
    window.onIframeLoad = function()
    {
        $scope.$apply(function()
        {
            $scope.dm.pages = $scope.dm.pages;
        });

    }
}
```

As you can see I have a MainDM (data model) that I'm sharing between controllers. dm.pages is an array that has nothing more than string values in order to set the pages menu items.

the iframe code looks like this.

```
<div class="col-md-8 content-wrapper" ng-controller="SiteTempCtrl">
    <iframe src="site.html" 
        width="{{percent}}%" 
        height="{{percent}}%" 
        onload="onIframeLoad()">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

When the onload event fires on the iframe I run the onIframeLoad() function in the controller. That fires off just fine. The problem is the AngularJS binding inside of the HTML that the loaded inside the iframe isn't working.

The code inside the iframe html looks like this.

```
<div class="main-nav " id="main_nav">
    <ul class="menu" id="main_nav_list" >
          <li ng-repeat='title in dm.pages'><a href='#'>{{title}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to get AngularJS to work with this type of HTML content. This is going to be really important as the user will have the option to change html templets and I'll be reloading HTML into that iframe over the corse of the user using the app and I will need to refresh angular in order to get bindings and functions to work.

Comment: Correct me if I interpreted your question wrong Matt. If understand accurately then you're essentially wrapping both the CMS and IFrame within one Angular app which I can't see working. I would suggest maybe considering communicating between them both using postMessage as described in this [post](http://newtriks.com/2013/05/13/using-postmessage-in-an-angularjs-application/).

Comment: Yes I would like it to all be wrapped in the same angular app. I'm wondering after the iframe fires onload I want to inject angular context into the html of the iframe.

Comment: The only hack I see is trying to share variables using window.top within the iframe JS and setting variables you need within your main app. This might turn very ugly.